# Deduce patterns of divisibility in bit strings

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, bit-strings

This is partially a computer science question, but belongs here as well.

The question has to do with the bit representation of integers. For simplicity, assume only non-negative integers. Can we find a general pattern for multiples of a positive integer in its bit representation?

That is, given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $S = \{s \mid s = kn, \space k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the set of multiples of n. Represent $S$ in binary, call it $B$. Can we find a general pattern/function for $B$ that exhaustively test every element of a set and see if it equals to $B$? If so, is there an algorithm for finding the pattern/function?

Comment: You may want to look at the [rules for divisibility for base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) and adapt the techniques used there for binary numbers as well.  For example, notice that every multiple of two has units digit zero and every multiple of four has units digit and twos digit both zero.  Multiples of three in binary will follow a similar rule as multiples of 11 by noting that $4,16,64,\dots,2^{2n}$ are all one more than a multiple of three and $2,8,32,\dots,2^{2n-1}$ are all one less than a multiple of three...

Comment: Alternatively, if you were looking to simply generate every element instead of having a test to see whether a particular element were in the set, you can just continually add $n$ to the most recently generated number...

Comment: right, I meant for testing only.